# what's the meaning of the word "topics" in sending messages asynchronously in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

When I reached chapter 8 named "Sending messages asynchronously" in the book named "Spring in Action 5",I met the word "topics" several times and still couldn't understand what's the meaning of it,so can anyone please make a clearer explanation?Thanks.

I have searched this word "topics" like "what's the meaning of topics in computer science?" but no answers.

The sentence which emerges the word "topics" in chapter 8 for example:

> Whereas RabbitMQ deals primarily with queues in exchanges, Kafka utilizes **topics** only to offer pub/sub messaging.(from 8.3 Messaging with Kafka)

Comment: It's a publish-subscribe channel, equivalent to a mailing list. Kafka specifically uses the word *topic* for its message queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a few words, a topic is a logical name for a messaging channel. In a Publish-Subscribe pattern, clients will subscribe to the topics (channels) within which the messages they are interested in, will be published.

Think of it like the tags here on Stack Overflow. If you are a Java developer, chances are you look at the questions tagged with Java primarily. Java is the topic in this context. If you click the "Watch Tag" button, you have subscribed to the Java topic.

It's from the publish-subscribe pattern.

[Wikipedia Publish-Subscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)